# Getting overlapping patterns using regex Java

Tags: java, regex, algorithm, overlap

this code is to extract sequential letters from a data-set

```
import java.util.regex.*;

public class IFS {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String a;
        a = "ABC1abc";

        regexchecker ("\\D+", a);
    }

    public static void regexchecker(String theRegex, String stuffToCheck) {
        // compiling the regex pattern
        Pattern checkRegex = Pattern.compile(theRegex);
        // the regex matcher being joined to the pattern
        Matcher regexmatcher = checkRegex.matcher(stuffToCheck);

        int end = stuffToCheck.length();
        for (int i = 0; i < end; i = i + 1) {

            for (int j = i + 1; j <= end; ++j) {

                regexmatcher.region(i, j);
                while (regexmatcher.find()) {
                    if (regexmatcher.group().length() != 0) {         

                        System.out.println(regexmatcher.group());
                    }
                }    
            }
        }
    }
}
```

OK so I understand that my code will iterate from `j` to end EVERY TIME but I need it to skip an iteration that gives the same out put.

my output is

> 1. A
> 2. AB
> 3. ABC
> 4. ABC
> 5. ABC
>        a
> 6. ABC ab
> 7. ABC abc

and so on  when I want an output like

> 1. A
> 2. B
> 3. C
> 4. a
> 5. b
> 6. c
> 7. AB
> 8. BC
> 9. ab
> 10. bc
> 11. ABC
> 12. abc

Any help is much appreciated. My original data-set is much larger than this but I have used a 7 character set for simplicity

Comment: Why would you use regex for this?

Comment: Is this a sequence where A then AB then ABC, but not AX ?

Comment: given your requirement description and the way you structured your code, I would say your desired output would be `A,AB,ABC,B,BC,C,a,ab,abc,b,bc,c`

Comment: @GUIDO yes I've edited my post accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Since you are setting the exact bounds you want to check in your region, you want to exclude matches that match only part of the region, as they will be found in a different iteration.  Since by default Matcher applies anchor bounds to the region when a region is set, use anchors in your regular expression to eliminate duplicate results:

```
    regexchecker ("^\\D+$", a);
```

Answer (score 0):

I made the following changes to your code:

```
1. Defined an ArrayList to filter those duplicate matches. 
2. Small changes on start/end index to the matcher's region 

import java.util.regex.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String a;
    a = "ABC1abc";

    regexchecker ("\\D+", a);
}

public static void regexchecker(String theRegex, String stuffToCheck) {
    // compiling the regex pattern
    Pattern checkRegex = Pattern.compile(theRegex);
    // the regex matcher being joined to the pattern
    Matcher regexmatcher = checkRegex.matcher(stuffToCheck);
    // define an ArrayList
    ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<>();

    int end = stuffToCheck.length();
    for (int i = 1; i <= end; i++) {

        for (int j = 0; j <= end-i; j++) {

            regexmatcher.region(j, j + i);
            while (regexmatcher.find()) {
                if (result.indexOf(regexmatcher.group()) == -1) {         

                    System.out.println(regexmatcher.group());
                    //result.add(regexmatcher.group());
                }
            }    
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
A
B
C
a
b
c
AB
BC
ab
bc
ABC
abc
```

Answer (score 0):

I find it easiest to grab the longest match first, then try to make successively shorter matches at the same starting position.  The `find()` in the outer loop locates the next match, then the inner loop sets the region to its bounds and steadily shrinks it.  I used `lookingAt()` in the inner loop because it automatically anchors the match to the beginning of the region; probably not necessary, but whatever, it was there. :D

```
public static void regexchecker(String regex, String source)
{
  Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
  Matcher m = p.matcher(source);
  int len = source.length();
  int start = 0;
  int end = len;

  while (start < len && m.region(start, len).find())
  {
    start = m.start();
    end = m.end();
    while (start < end && m.region(start, end).lookingAt())
    {
      System.out.println(m.group());
      end = m.end() - 1;
    }
    start++;
  }
}
```

output:

```
ABC
AB
A
BC
B
C
abc
ab
a
bc
b
c
```